# QGIS2WEB - OpenLayers - Improvement Popup by adding "highlight feature"

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3

QGIS2WEB exports a map that allows to query by click multiple layers and multiple features at the same time, showing all the result in the outgoing popup as in this example where 6 different layers are queried.
I would like to **add the ability to selectively highlight the query feature**.
Do you know how to do it? I thought of a graphic with a button (I did it with photoshop):

example of 6 features queried in different layers
[image]

example whit highlight button for any feature
[image]

The code for highlighting is already present in qgis2web as pointermove, could this be reused and applied in the popup? I leave it written as an example:

```
if (doHighlight) {
                if (currentFeature !== highlight) {
                    if (highlight) {
                        featureOverlay.getSource().removeFeature(highlight);
                    }
                    if (currentFeature) {
                        var styleDefinition = currentLayer.getStyle().toString();

                        if (currentFeature.getGeometry().getType() == 'Point') {
                            var radius = styleDefinition.split('radius')[1].split(' ')[1];

                            highlightStyle = new ol.style.Style({
                                image: new ol.style.Circle({
                                    fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                                        color: 'rgba(255,255,0,1)'
                                    }),
                                    radius: radius,
                                    stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                                      color: 'rgba(255, 255, 0, 1)',
                                      width: 3
                                    }),
                                })
                            })
                        } else if (currentFeature.getGeometry().getType() == 'LineString') {

                            var featureWidth = styleDefinition.split('width')[1].split(' ')[1].replace('})','');

                            highlightStyle = new ol.style.Style({
                                stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                                    color: 'rgba(255,255,0,1)',
                                    lineDash: null,
                                    width: featureWidth
                                })
                            });

                        } else {
                            highlightStyle = new ol.style.Style({
                                        
                                    fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                                      color: 'rgba(255, 255, 0, 0)'
                                    }),
                                    stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                                      color: 'rgba(255, 255, 0, 1)',
                                      lineDash: [10, 10],
                                      width: 3
                                    }),                         
                            })
                        }
                        featureOverlay.getSource().addFeature(currentFeature);
                        featureOverlay.setStyle(highlightStyle);
                    }
                    highlight = currentFeature;
                }
            }
```

This is the graphical output

[image]

The entire current popup code, **which I ask you to change**, is this:

```
var onSingleClick = function(evt) {
    if (doHover) {
        return;
    }
    if (sketch) {
        return;
    }
    var pixel = map.getEventPixel(evt.originalEvent);
    var coord = evt.coordinate;
    var popupField;
    var currentFeature;
    var currentFeatureKeys;
    var clusteredFeatures;
    var popupText = '<ul>';
    map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(pixel, function(feature, layer) {
        if (feature instanceof ol.Feature && (layer.get("interactive") || layer.get("interactive") == undefined)) {
            var doPopup = false;
            for (k in layer.get('fieldImages')) {
                if (layer.get('fieldImages')[k] != "Hidden") {
                    doPopup = true;
                }
            }
            currentFeature = feature;
            clusteredFeatures = feature.get("features");
            var clusterFeature;
            if (typeof clusteredFeatures !== "undefined") {
                if (doPopup) {
                    for(var n=0; n<clusteredFeatures.length; n++) {
                        clusterFeature = clusteredFeatures[n];
                        currentFeatureKeys = clusterFeature.getKeys();
                        popupText += '<li><table>'
                        for (var i=0; i<currentFeatureKeys.length; i++) {
                            if (currentFeatureKeys[i] != 'geometry') {
                                popupField = '';
                                if (layer.get('fieldLabels')[currentFeatureKeys[i]] == "inline label") {
                                popupField += '<th>' + layer.get('fieldAliases')[currentFeatureKeys[i]] + ':</th><td>';
                                } else {
                                    popupField += '<td colspan="2">';
                                }
                                if (layer.get('fieldLabels')[currentFeatureKeys[i]] == "header label") {
                                    popupField += '<strong>' + layer.get('fieldAliases')[currentFeatureKeys[i]] + ':</strong><br />';
                                }
                                if (layer.get('fieldImages')[currentFeatureKeys[i]] != "ExternalResource") {
                                    popupField += (clusterFeature.get(currentFeatureKeys[i]) != null ? autolinker.link(clusterFeature.get(currentFeatureKeys[i]).toLocaleString()) + '</td>' : '');
                                } else {
                                    popupField += (clusterFeature.get(currentFeatureKeys[i]) != null ? '<img src="images/' + clusterFeature.get(currentFeatureKeys[i]).replace(/[\\\/:]/g, '_').trim()  + '" /></td>' : '');
                                }
                                popupText += '<tr>' + popupField + '</tr>';
                            }
                        } 
                        popupText += '</table></li>';    
                    }
                }
            } else {
                currentFeatureKeys = currentFeature.getKeys();
                if (doPopup) {
                    popupText += '<li><table>';
                    for (var i=0; i<currentFeatureKeys.length; i++) {
                        if (currentFeatureKeys[i] != 'geometry') {
                            popupField = '';
                            if (layer.get('fieldLabels')[currentFeatureKeys[i]] == "inline label") {
                                popupField += '<th>' + layer.get('fieldAliases')[currentFeatureKeys[i]] + ':</th><td>';
                            } else {
                                popupField += '<td colspan="2">';
                            }
                            if (layer.get('fieldLabels')[currentFeatureKeys[i]] == "header label") {
                                popupField += '<strong>' + layer.get('fieldAliases')[currentFeatureKeys[i]] + ':</strong><br />';
                            }
                            if (layer.get('fieldImages')[currentFeatureKeys[i]] != "ExternalResource") {
                                popupField += (currentFeature.get(currentFeatureKeys[i]) != null ? autolinker.link(currentFeature.get(currentFeatureKeys[i]).toLocaleString()) + '</td>' : '');
                            } else {
                                popupField += (currentFeature.get(currentFeatureKeys[i]) != null ? '<img src="images/' + currentFeature.get(currentFeatureKeys[i]).replace(/[\\\/:]/g, '_').trim()  + '" /></td>' : '');
                            }
                            popupText += '<tr>' + popupField + '</tr>';
                        }
                    }
                    popupText += '</table>';
                }
            }
        }
    });
    if (popupText == '<ul>') {
        popupText = '';
    } else {
        popupText += '</ul>';
    }
    
    var viewProjection = map.getView().getProjection();
    var viewResolution = map.getView().getResolution();
    for (i = 0; i < wms_layers.length; i++) {
        if (wms_layers[i][1]) {
            var url = wms_layers[i][0].getSource().getGetFeatureInfoUrl(
                evt.coordinate, viewResolution, viewProjection,
                {
                    'INFO_FORMAT': 'text/html',
                });
            if (url) {
                popupText = popupText + '<iframe style="width:100%;height:110px;border:0px;" id="iframe" seamless src="' + url + '"></iframe>';
            }
        }
    }

    if (popupText) {
        overlayPopup.setPosition(coord);
        content.innerHTML = popupText;
        container.style.display = 'block';        
    } else {
        container.style.display = 'none';
        closer.blur();
    }
};
```

You can help me?
Thank you

Comment: If this is a feature request for QGIS2Web then you might want to post this in their appropriate channels e.g. on GitHub instead of here.

Comment: Thanks, I will also open an issue in github, however I thought that by writing here it would be possible to involve more people as anyone who knows openlayers3 and javascript could be able to develop the solution.